# How to write into a file using XML

Tags: xml

I want to create a file "cds.lib" in XML. The file should contain

```
DEFINE work ./work
DEFINE proasic3 ./lib  
include /tools/cadence_8.2/IUS8.2/tools.lnx86/inca/files/cds.lib
```

Below is the XML code I tried. `touch` command is working. But `echo` is not working. Nothing is written in the file "cds.lib", it is empty. Please give an alternate way to write into a file.

```
<runnable name="compile_ncsim" type="group">
   <members>
      <member>common_compile</member>
   </members>

   <execScript>
      <command>touch cds.lib </command>
      <command>echo "DEFINE work ./work" >> cds.lib </command>
      <command>echo "DEFINE (%LIB_NAME%) ./lib" >> cds.lib </command>
      <command>echo "include (%CDS_INSTALL_DIR%)/inca/files/cds.lib" >> cds.lib </command>
   </execScript>
</runnable>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you've shown is just an XML file. Presumably you've got something which "executes" this XML file, but you haven't told us what that is.

Comment: XML is just a markup language. Not programming language which could do this.